# Python Django - update booleanField via List View

Tags: python, django

Is there any way how to update booleanField in the list view? In list view I have listed all my orders and I need to mark which are done and which are not done. I know I can update it via UpdateView, but that is not user friendly because I have to leave the listview page.

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ...
    order = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    completed = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
```

views.py

```
class OrderIndex(generic.ListView):

   template_name = "mypage.html"
   context_object_name = "orders"

   def get_queryset(self):
      return Order.objects.all().order_by("-id")
```

mypage.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for order in orders%}
   User: {{ order.user}} | Completed: {{order.completed}} <input 
   type="checkbox">
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit">
{% endblock %}
```

I am quite new to the django framework and have no idea how to make it work.

Comment: If you want to stay on the same page, then you will probably need something like Javascript and Ajax to update those boolean fields. Have you considered this?

Comment: @DanielHolmes Thank you for your reply. No I have not. Unfortunately I am not familiar with Javascript nor Ajax.

Answer (score 3):

like this should look you javascript

```
const updateField = (order_id) =>{
    var form = new FormData();

    form.append('order_id', order_id);

    fetch('{% url "url_updateField" %}', {
      method:'post',
      body:form,
      mode:'cors',
      cache:'default',
      credentials:'include',
    }).then((response)=>{
      console.log('field update as well')
   })
})
```

just add a function to your button on envent onclick

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for order in orders%}
   User: {{ order.user}} | Completed: {{order.completed}} <input 
   type="checkbox" onclick="updateField({{order.pk}})">
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit">
{% endblock %}
```

then in your view you should have the below view to process the request

```
def updateField(request):
    print(request.body.get('order_id'))
    #you should update you model field here 
    return JsonResponse({'ok':True}, status=200)
```

[This will help you How to work with ajax request with django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html)

Answer (score 0):

Combine the UpdateView with the part of the listView's functionality by adding to the UpdateView the extra context of the entire list of objects:

```
class OrderUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Order
    form_class = OrderForm

    ....

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['orders'] = Order.objects.all().order_by("-id") 
        return context
```

Consider a simple template where the entire list is displayed on top, and the bottom has a form allowing the user to update a particular item in the list. 
This approach purposefully avoids using Ajax and javascript.

[documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#contextmixin)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this without any special magic, just post to an update view from your listview with the entire form filled out correctly in hidden form fields nothing special needs to be done anywhere else.

```
<!-- todo_list.html -->
<form method="POST" action="update/{{object.id}}/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="completed" value="true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{object.name}}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="due_date" value="{{object.due_date|date:'Y-m-d'}}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="details" value="{{object.details}}" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Not Done</button>
</form>
```